# Insert text from dynamic text boxes to database

Tags: asp.net

i had created a text box control array using the following code, where the no.of controls are generated on the basics of the value selected from the combo box

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim lstTextBox = New List(Of TextBox)()

        For i As Integer = 0 To DropDownList1.SelectedValue
          for j as integer =0 to 3
            Dim txtbx As New TextBox()
            txtbx.ID = String.Format("txtbx{0}", j)
            lstTextBox.Add(txtbx)
            txtbx.Text = "sample text " & j
            form1.Controls.Add(txtbx)
           next
        Next
        Session("lstTextBox") = lstTextBox
        End Sub
```

now i need to insert the value to the database on a single button click, here the code is

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
     dim mysql as string 
     mysql="insert into mytable values("
        Dim lstText = New List(Of TextBox)()
        lstText = Session("lstTextBox")
        For i As Integer = 0 To lstText.Count - 1
         for j as integer =0 to 3            
          mysql= mysql & "'" & trim(lstText(j).Text) & "',"
         next
```

'execute insert for each row with the mysql string
            Next
        End Sub

now the problem is: only the initial values in the text boxes are inserted to the database, the changes which i had made in the text boxes are not inserted to the database. ie, in session the initial values will not change on text change in the text box.

i need a solution for this problem for proceeding my work. so expert's kind attention please.. positive responses will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about VB and as well as My Sql. But i can give you a some way to get rid off from Session

Try like this in DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged,

```
if(Session("lstTextBox"))==null
   Session("lstTextBox") = lstTextBox
 else
     Session.Abandon()
     Session("lstTextBox") = lstTextBox
```

Now you go can check whether session is updating or not. As well as you may get the result as you want. Please let me know the output.

Comment: the session is generated at the time of controls are generated, hence the session variable holds the initial values of text boxes. if i made any change in the text boxes are not affecting the session variable that's is the problem

Comment: Actually where the session variable gets defined ?. As per your code, the session gets defined on DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged. If it's true, then you may proceed with my answer. The initial textbox values will be cleared at the stage of abandon. Hence the textbox value will be renewed as you want.